# F# Async and WPF ProgressBar

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, mvvm, f#, progress-bar

I've got a function that downloads a website:

```ml
let downloadPage (address : string) =
    async
        {
             // do some magic here
        }
```

It's type is "string -> Async string".

I want to download several pages - let "pagesToDownload" be a seq containing all of them. Then I can write:

```ml
pagesToDownload
|> Seq.map downloadPage
|> Async.Parallel
|> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This works fine, however it takes some time to accomplish. I'm planning to use this function in my UI, so it would be nice to provide e.g. a ProgressBar.

I found a nice article on using a ProgressBar in WPF:
http://elegantcode.com/2009/07/03/wpf-multithreading-using-the-backgroundworker-and-reporting-the-progress-to-the-ui/

but I can't see how to combine these two ideas. The module that downloads websites is written in F#, while UI (ViewModel and View) - in C#.

Comment: You could accept [`IProgress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138298%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use the default [`Progress<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193692%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation as a parameter in the method downloading a bunch of pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way to handle this is to use [FSharp.ViewModule's Progress](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.ViewModule/blob/master/src/FSharp.ViewModule/Progress.fs) support.  It includes a `ProgressManager` class, which provides a functional style API to update progress, and internally wraps a `Progress<T>` for you.

This makes it simple to bind to directly from the WPF UI.  For an example, see the [Visual F# Power Tools Rename dialog](https://github.com/fsprojects/VisualFSharpPowerTools/blob/master/src/FSharp.Editing.VisualStudio/Gui/RenameDialog.xaml#L77-L80).  Just make sure to create the instance in your VM on the main thread/SynchronizationContext, and it'll "just work".  (This typically just means building this in a let binding or similar in the ViewModel type.)

If you don't want to take on the dependency for `FSharp.ViewModule` (which I'd recommend and suggest is worthwhile if you're using F# for WPF backed MVVM ViewModels), you could easily adapt the code linked above to your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Reed, unfortunately both links are broken. Would you have any other examples?

Comment: @Goswin I just fixed the links :)